# How to get order Id in class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Shipping_Method_Form?

Tags: magento-1

How to get order Id in class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Shipping_Method_Form ?`

I tried out many ways such as, `$this->getQuote->getId();`, `$this->getOrder->getId();` etc etc... But no Use. I am new in magento and extremely new to Its zend based module structure.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: ... maybe: getQuote()

Comment: getQuote() is implemented. Should return a quote, this has `getOrigOrderId()` and `getReservedOrderId()` with it, you can load the order? Did you try var_dump($this->getData())?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt is his code it calls getQuote as a property not as a method

Answer (score 4):

First, do you want the quote id or the order id?

If you are after the quote id, try: `$this->getQuote()->getId()` (note that `getQuote` is a method).

If you are after order id, I am afraid you cannot do this. The order is created when you press the "place order" button so when you see the output of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Shipping_Method_Form`, no order exists in the system yet. Only the quote is available at this time.

Comment: Yea. It makes sense. I tried out getting Id using get params also. but no luck!

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem might be a typo in your code. It looks like you are accesing methods as if they where properties.

Change `$this->getQuote->getId();` into `$this->getQuote()->getId();`

This should work as the quote object is being accessed in that same block in line 140 within `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Shipping_Method_Form::getShippingPrice()`

Comment: I returned The quote Id is already returned using `echo $this->getQuote()->getId();` ... But It wont return order Id as you said!

Comment: There is no order Id at that point. The order will be created and assigned an Id once you finish the order creation process (basically when you submit the form)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do the following, assuming that the order id has been reserved on the quote at the time you're accessing this method.

```
$order_id = $this->getQuote()->getReservedOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
```

Comment: you mean `Mage::getModel('sales/order')`